# process argument with spaces

Tags: c#

hi i need to have argument that contain spaces.

in this case `/SASE Lab Tools` is the subject. Under normal command line:

`sslist -R -H -h sinsscm01.ds.net "/SASE Lab Tools"`

how do i make that happen? Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "sslist.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-R -H -h sinsscm01.ds.net /SASE Lab Tools";
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-R -H -h sinsscm01.ds.net \"/SASE Lab Tools\"";
```

Also escape sequence list may be interesting for you - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-R -H -h sinsscm01.ds.net ""/SASE Lab Tools""";
```

This syntax will prevent other problems from occurring (e.g. with escapes of things like `C:\my\path\to\afile.txt` etc)